# How to change a Javascript variable depending on media queries?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to change a Javascript variable depending on CSS media queries? for eg. I have a variable in javascript called `deviceSize` and this is set to `desktop` by default. And I have 3 different media queries for Desktop Tablet and Mobile. How can I make Javascript know the media query that it is being used?

I want to do this because I want to disable certain features of my game in mobile. My game is a minesweeper game, and it has three difficulty levels. It starts with a 16x16 grid because of `deviceSize`. So I want javascript to change this variable depending on the media query that CSS detects. So I set `deviceSize` to mobile and start the game with a 8x8 grid.

Here is my game:
https://github.com/sacredcandies/minesweeper

Comment: I wouldn't think this would involve media queries.  You should be able to add a resize event to the window, and on resize check the width of the page to determine what the deviceSize should be.

Comment: You can relay on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: Make your acquaintance with [w3schools: How TO - Media Queries with JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp)

Answer (score 1):

try this to get the width and height

```
 function getWidthAndHeight() {
      let width= window.innerWidth;
      let height= window.innerHeight;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... there are more direct answers, as noted in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `window.innerWidth` to determine the size of the display?

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

Comment: Not all media queries are pixel based.  It would be better to match the media query itself, to be consistent with the CSS.

Comment: OP's variable is named `deviceSize`, which would suggest it's the size of the device he's looking at with his media query.